# Unexpected behaviour when creating a Unicode Windows application

Tags: windows, visual-c++

I am creating an application framework library, so I want all the startup related code to reside in a library so that the application doesn't need to be concerned with it. The framework calls a factory method in the application to return a new object derived from a base Application class.

I created a static library where I have a wWinMain function. It is built as a Unicode project in Visual Studio 2022.

When I now create a Unicode application and link the above-mentioned static library, I get an unresolved external symbol error

> MSVCRTD.lib(exe_winmain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol WinMain referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)

Notably some of the configuration that I have which I think might be related.

Compiler options.

- Configuration Type: Application (.exe)
- Windows SDK Version: 10.0 (latest installed version)
- Platform Toolset: Visual Studio 2022 (v143)
- Character Set: Use Unicode Character Set
- MSVC Toolset Version: Default
- Runtime Library: Multi-threaded DLL

Linker options.

- SubSystem: Windows

My library code for wWinMain is

```
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    PWSTR     lpCmdLine,
                    int       nShowCmd)
{
    (void)hInstance;
    (void)hPrevInstance;

    // Convert the command line into an argument list
    int           nargs;
    const LPWSTR* args = CommandLineToArgvW(lpCmdLine, &nargs);

    .
    .
    .
}
```

however, if I change the above signature to

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
                   int       nShowCmd)
```

and comment out the rest of the code that deals with the Unicode, the build is successful, but I lose the Unicode.

If I add the wWinMain function to my application code, it works but is definitely not what I want to do. What seems strange to me is that I never got a duplicate symbol error when my library code was changed back to using wWinMain

If I change the Entry point to wWinMainCRTStartup, it works.

My expectations were that it should have worked without me having to be explicit about the entry point.

Could I be doing something incorrect or is this just normal behaviour when placing the Unicode version of WinMain function in an external library instead of the executable application project.

Cheers for any insights.

Comment: This is a build configuration issue, so we need to see your Makefile or project file or whatever it is that you use to build the project. (The issue is with the application, not the library.)

Comment: "change the Entry point" is where it went wrong.  The normal setting is *blank*, leaving it up to the linker to find either WinMain or wWinMain.

Comment: @RaymondChen I have updated my post to include some of the build settings

Comment: @HansPassant The problem was with leaving it blank. Only when I specifically tell the linker to use wWinMainCRTStartup does the project build successfully. My expectation is that it would have used the correct entrypoint because the Application is being built for Unicode

Comment: No, the Unicode selection does not affect the linker.  If it was blank before, I suspect that the issue is caused by the linker having trouble locating the entrypoint since it lives in a library.  It is a very unusual approach.  The workaround you found probably is the correct one.

Comment: "[The linker will attempt to infer which entry point is needed by walking the symbol table of your objs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45246224)." But neither WinMain nor wWinMain are in your objs; they are in a library, so the linker is stymied. It's unusual for a library to have wWinMain, since it means that a program can't use two such libraries. Rename the library function to `wContosoWinMain` and have the executable's `wWinMain` forward its parameters to `wContosoWinMain`, That way you can also have a `wFabrikamWinMain` in some other library, and the main exe might choose between them.

Comment: Thanks @RaymondChen My use case is for application framework where I do not want the application to have to deal with WinMain. I will edit the post to reflect this as it might provide some more insight.